# C++ library for generating a SOAP message using WSDL

Tags: c++, soap, wsdl

Do you know of any C++ libraries can can generate SOAP messages using the WSDL. I am writing a C++ client application and am looking for such a library. I however cannot use gSoap and wsdlpull. SOAP Client library (SQLData Systems) looks like another library which could help me (though I am not too sure) but its results page shows an error while dealing with Apache Axis and I might have to use that. Are there any other libraries? Thanks for the help.

Regards,
Harsha

Comment: What is the issue for which you cannot use gSOAP?

Comment: @Kangkan Perhaps licensing? If you use the open source version the code generated by `soapcpp2` is to be licensed under GPLv2 unless you get the standard or enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the code generated by Axis is cleaner than the code generated by gsoap. What I dislike in Axis is that you need a JVM in order to generate the code from WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you mention Apache Axis, there's a C++ implementation of Axis [here](http://ws.apache.org/axis/cpp/index.html)

Comment: Hi, 
I had actually looked at Apache Axis C++ one, but from what I understood, this library will give me the client stubs for a particular wsdl. Now the thing is that I cannot change my client program. So I need something that would enable me to just serialize the SOAP. Can Axis C++ do that? I am not completely sure of Axis C++ myself. I cannot use gSOAP due to some licensing issues. 

Thanks for the reply. 

Harsha